# как сменить тип полей в таблице mysql не указывая названия полей, а по номерам полей (те номера, которые вижу через phpmyadmin)?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть несколько таблиц, с большим кол-вом полей (198) - не спрашивайте почему - пока так удобно, нужно.
Цель - уйти от указания в запросе имен полей.

Вопрос:
Существует ли запрос, которым можно сменить тип поля, всем полям номера которых укажу в запросе?

Или команда на смену типа сразу всем полям в таблице.

Comment: Поля - в MySQL. Номера - в PHP. Нет, нельзя.

Comment: если сменить тип всем полям в таблице?

Comment: Dynamic SQL. Запрос в INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS и итерация по полученному набору.

Comment: Спасибо. Поля получил. Пробую переименовать - получаю ошибку:
#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около ''1_db1_1block_main

Запрос применяю такой:
ALTER TABLE '1_db1_1block_main'
MODIFY COLUMN top1_check_how_many_links LONGTEXT
MODIFY COLUMN top2_check_how_many_links LONGTEXT
MODIFY COLUMN top3_check_how_many_links LONGTEXT

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Извините, 1й день на форуме.
  Ушел разбираться, как тут форматировать для читабельности сообщений..

Comment: запятые то не нужны там?

Comment: и имя таблицы в обратных кавычках, а не одинарных

Comment: то есть ругается то он у вас на кавычки, но когда поправите будет ругаться на отсутствие запятых.

Comment: напишите, плиз, как мой запрос должен выглядеть в корректном виде